# rails protect_from_forgery raises with exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf-protection

I have Rails project which is working on production.
But on localhost it raises on every POST request with `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`. I know what is it.
AuthToken is protection from csrf attacks. I have in my *application_controller.rb*

`protect_from_forgery with: :exception #this line raise exception`

and `csrf_meta_tags` present.
I have no any problems in other Rails projects with it.

If I remove param `with: :exception` session will reset after reloading page.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

Project has config in *config/environments/development.rb*

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'my_project.dev:3000'`

I tried to load project on *localhost:3000*, but url was *my_project.dev:3000*.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Comment: this param resets session. ```protect_from_forgery``` has param ```with: :null_session``` by default.